# How can I calculate the partial trace for a combined state of a pair of two-level atoms to get a reduced state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, density-operator

Let's say I have a  combined state of a pair of two-level atoms, $A$ and $B$, given by the density matrix:

$$
\rho = \frac{1}{2}\mid g_A, g_B \rangle \langle g_A, g_B\mid + \frac{1}{2} \mid g_A, e_B \rangle \langle g_A,e_B \mid
$$

where $\mid g \rangle$ and $\mid e \rangle$ refer to ground and excited states, respectively.  How might I go about calculating the reduced state for system $A$ or system $B$? I've read through some books but I've struggled to actually apply it.  I understand that if you want the reduced state for system $A$, you must trace over system $B$, but what this actually means in real, mathematical terms I do not understand.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The partial trace with respect to $B$ is a map from the operators on the hilbert space $A \otimes B$ to the operators in $A$ given as follows

$\langle \phi | Tr_B (\rho_{AB}) |\psi \rangle = \sum_n \langle \phi| \langle n | \rho_{AB} | \psi \rangle | n \rangle$

Where $\psi,\phi$ are vectors in A, and $|n\rangle$ is a basis in B.

So, in your example:

$\langle x|Tr_B (\rho) |y \rangle = \delta_{g_A,x} \ \delta_{g_A,y}$

therefore $Tr_B(\rho) = |g_a \rangle \langle g_a |$

I leave to you the computation of $Tr_A(\rho)$

Answer (score 0):

Simply to say, just abandon the terms corresponding to the part on which the partial trace is applied. For example, 
$$
\rho = \sum_i c_i |A_i,B_i\rangle \langle A_i,B_i|,
$$
then 
$$
{\rm Tr}_B[\rho] = \sum_i c_i |A_i\rangle \langle A_i|,
$$
while
$$
{\rm Tr}_A[\rho] = \sum_i c_i |B_i\rangle \langle B_i|.
$$
In your case, $i=1,2$, $A_1 = A_2 = g_A$, $B_1 = g_B, B_2 = e_B$.